# ¿Como trasladar botones de un div a otro con JQuery al presionarlos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola a todos/as de esta maravillosa comunidad, tengo la siguiente inquietud: Deseo trasladar unos botones que se encuentran en un div para moverlos a otro div cuando los presiono uno por uno y al aparecer en el otro div, cuando los presione de nuevo, me gustaria que retornaran a su posicion inicial. Hasta el momento se como trasladarlos de un div hacia otro, pero no se como retornarlos a su posicion inicial.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Python').click(function(){
        $("#content").append($('#Python').hide());
        $("#contenido").append($('#Python').show());
     });
     $('#Django').click(function(){
        $("#content").append($('#Django').hide());
        $("#contenido").append($('#Django').show());
     });
     $('#Jython').click(function(){
        $("#content").append($('#Jython').hide());
        $("#contenido").append($('#Jython').show());
     });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
 <button  id="Python"  class="btn btn-info">Python</button>
 <button id="Django"  class="btn btn-info">Django</button>
 <button  id="Jython"  class="btn btn-info">Jython</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div id ="contenido" >
   <!--Div donde se pasarán los botones-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La jugada esta al inicio, verificando en que div se encuentra el boton.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn").click(function() {

      if( $(this).parent().attr("id") == "content" ){
          $(this).detach().appendTo('#contenido');
      }
      else{
          $(this).detach().appendTo('#content'); 
      }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="content">
     <button  id="Python"  class="btn btn-info">Python</button>
     <button id="Django"  class="btn btn-info">Django</button>
     <button  id="Jython"  class="btn btn-info">Jython</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id ="contenido" >
       <!--Div donde se pasarán los botones-->
    </div>
```

Comment: Genial,  Muchas gracias, esto era lo que andaba buscando.

Answer (score 0):

una manera de solucionarlo es:

```
  const ObtenerDestino=function(id)
  {
   var padre= $('#'+id).parent().attr('id');

  return  padre == 'content' ? 'contenido':'content' ;

  };



    $('#Python').click(function(){
    var padreDestino = ObtenerDestino($('#Python').attr('id'));

           $('#'+padreDestino).append($('#Python').show());

        });
```

//para los otros botones solo debes repetir la implementacion